# scipy.optimize: how to return all possible solutions?

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, nonlinear-optimization

I am trying two solve a set of two nonlinear trigonometric equations. It is a simple inverse kinematics of 2link manipulator. My code looks like this and the function gives me the correct solution. But this set has two possible solutions. How do I modify the fsolve so it returns all of the real solutions?:

```
def equations(p):
        theta2, theta3 = p
        f1 = L[1]*math.cos(math.radians(theta2))+L[2]*math.cos(math.radians(theta2+theta3))-(x3-2*Pos1[0][i])
        f2 = L[1]*math.sin(math.radians(theta2))+L[2]*math.sin(math.radians(theta2+theta3))-(y3-2*Pos1[1][i])
    return (f1,f2)
theta2, theta3 = fsolve(equations,(1,1))
```

Comment: Is there any way to separate the two answers? How does the program choose one answer over the other?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know. I solved this system analytically on paper and there are two possible solutions - that is for sure. The solution that comes from the program is among them but I don't know how to make it return both of them

Comment: Every numerical equation solver will return a single solution. What solution it returns depends on the starting search point. Unfortunately, in most cases, you cannot know beforehand if two different starting points will lead to different solutions. What you can only do is try different starting points and hope that the two solutions will be obtained.